# Remove all dots in filename except the dot before the file extension

Tags: php, filenames, sanitization

I am trying to sanitize a filename.

I would like to know of a way to remove all decimals from a files name except the last one. I need to keep the last one because the extension follows that.

EXAMPLE:

```
abc.def.ghij-klmnop.q234.mp3
```

This file should look like

```
abcdefghij-klmnopq234.mp3
```

Some extensions are longer than 3 characters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a regex with a positive lookahead. Like this:

```
$withdots = 'abc.def.ghij-klmnop.q234.mp3';
$nodots = preg_replace('/\.(?=.*\.)/', '', $withdots);
```

After executing the above, `$nodots` will contain `abcdefghij-klmnopq234.mp3`. The regular expression is basically saying match all periods that are followed by another period. So the last period won't match. We replace all matches with an empty string, and we're left with the desired result.

Answer (score 9):

That should do it:

```
$file = 'abc.def.ghij-klmnop.q234.mp3';
$parts = pathinfo($file);
$filename = str_replace('.', '', $parts['filename']).'.'.$parts['extension'];
```

Comment: The easiest to read solution, except it won't work properly if the file has no extension.

Answer (score 4):

You could also do this, it should be faster then using pathinfo & str_replace.

```
$parts  = explode('.', 'abc.def.ghij-klmnop.q234.mp3');
$ext    = array_pop($parts);
$nodots = implode('', $parts) . '.' . $ext;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `$s` is the name of the file.

```
$s = (($i = strrpos($s, '.')) === false) ? $s :
    str_replace('.','',substr($s,0,$i)).substr($s,$i);
```